# JSON to Dynamic Object vs. Strongly Typed Object

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm not sure if I don't get the big picture or if I just miss something but what are the benefits of parsing a JSON-String to a dynamic object?

If I have a class like this

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

and I use the HttpClient to get the object like this

```
Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
```

What do I benefit from this code?

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic product = JObject.Parse(content);
```

If I want to use them I need to write

```
product.Name
```

With the strongly typed apporach I at least have the intellisense. If the service changes the Product the dynamic approach doesn't help me either because I still need to access it like I mentioned above.

So what am I missing? Why should I use dynamics or when?

Comment: I generally use `dynamics` when I don't care about a certain property being deserialised. So if this property is a deep object graph and I have no use for it in the backend, I will say this is dynamic. Otherwise, I always tend to have strongly typed deserialisations because that is more useful to me in C#. It's safer to traverse a static typed object graph.

Comment: dynamics are resolved at runtime, var at compile time. so you have no intellisense, because you dont know, what to expect.

i am pretty new to c# sharp, so thats all i can tell. i used dynamic myself on a json to parse it and write it to a database and it worked in my case...luck i guess. i would go for the class type ;)

Comment: What if the service you are consuming changes the data format? Using `dynamic`, as long as that field exists, they can change the other ones without breaking your code. Its also useful for when you don't know exactly the data structure of the incoming data. Its not a "this or that" question, but a decision you make based on design requirements and knowledge about upstream systems and services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will **always** prefer to use a strong type over a dynamic (performance\convenience).

Here are some cases you would like to use a dynamic:

1. When you want to parse an xml and dont want to work with XElement's, XPath's etc.
2. COM interop - It makes things really easy and nice (try working with Excel\Word and you will be convinced).
3. In some cases it's nicer and readable to use a dynamic instead of reflection.