# How to deserilize array of json Object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi I want to read Id from JSON object which returns from Web Service  :

> [{"id":11,"username":"test5"}]

Code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

using (response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result)
{
    try
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //200 Ok
        string responJsonText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject res = JObject.Parse(responJsonText);
       //if ((int)res["id"][0] > 0)
       // {
            var uid = (int)res["id"][0];
            if (uid > 0)
            {
                return uid;
            }
            else
            { return 0; }
       // }
       // else
       //{ return 0; }
    }
```

How i can read the Id and username from Json Response using C#?

I get an exception with the following message:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: what exact issue / error are you facing with your code? I wonder if the async operation is a problem - you perhaps need to await it otherwise it won't be ready before you move to the next line and try to read the response. `res["id"][0]` also doesn't make much sense because the id is not an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1 - deserialize into C# models:

You can create a model that matches your json structure:

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize the json string, using Newtonsoft.Json nuget package as follows:

```
string json = @"[{""id"":11,""username"":""test5""}]";
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
```

## Solution 2 - parsing the json using JArray

```
string json = @"[{""id"":11,""username"":""test5""}]";

JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
int id = array.First["id"].Value<int>();
string username = array.First["username"].Value<string>();
```

I'm assuming the array will contain at least 1 element and there will be an `id` and `username` property. Proper error handling code should be added.

Comment: Can we not deserialize without using the class?

Comment: What are you looking to deserialize to? A dynamic?

Comment: @JimLobo yes there are other ways to parse the json, but if you need both id and username then I suggest you to do it using a class.

Comment: @JimLobo you can deserialize it as a dynamic but it's much more fragile. The best way is to create a model.

Comment: I would prefer Dynamic  way if not I can  use deserialization

Comment: @JimLobo I suggest you to reconsider the usage of dynamics in this case - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118624/json-to-dynamic-object-vs-strongly-typed-object and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370609/dynamic-vs-strongly-typed-elements

Comment: Thanks, Rui Jarimba, Works perfectly.